# How is it that a {} block can represent a function in scala?

Tags: scala

How is it that this:

```
List(1,2,3).zipWithIndex.map((tup) => tup match {case (v, i) => if (i == 1) 777 else v})
```

can be reduced to this:

```
List(1,2,3).zipWithIndex.map({case (v, i) => if (i == 1) 777 else v})
```

In other words, how is it that the `{}` block can be substituted for a function? How is scala directed to perform a match on the input to the `{}` block when it is never specified that it should do so? What exactly is a `{}` block anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A block (just `{}`) is not a function, it is an expression (this one is of type Unit).

The following code is an expression that, once evaluated, returns a Function1 or PartialFunction (as you can see it has a parameter).

```
{ case (v, i) => if (i == 1) 777 else v }
```

You can assign that to a variable (functions are objects)

```
val f1:Function1[Tuple2[Int, Int], Int] = { case (v, i) => if (i == 1) 777 else v }

val f2:PartialFunction[Tuple2[Int, Int], Int] = { case (v, i) => if (i == 1) 777 else v }
```

There is no need to set a type to function parameters because of type inference. In my example my val type gives me the types. In your example your `map` needs `(Int, Int) => Int`, then the compiler infers that type.

You can also write

```
List(1, 2, 3).zipWithIndex.map { case (v, i) => if (i == 1) 777 else v }
```

The use of `{}` is necessary if you want to use pattern matching with function parameters (case).

Without the `case` there is no need to use `{}`

```
List(1, 2, 3).zipWithIndex.map( p => if(p._2 == 1) 777 else p._1 )
```